# Unable to find version '2.0.21' of package 'LinqToFacebook'

Tags: linq, nopcommerce, nuget-package-restore

I'm working with NopCommerce 2.60, and suddenly I'm getting this error when I run the project

NuGet Package restore failed for project Nop.Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook: Unable to find version '2.0.21' of package 'LinqToFacebook'..

I tried to restore the package by NuGet but got the same error and the wired thing is that I cannot find even the reference to LinqToFacebook in project "Reference", also search for the LinqToFacebook.dll in package folder but is not there.

Any help would be great

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the package.config inside Facebook Plugin and remove or comment the reference to LinqToFacebook
that solved the error thwon by Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error, and I'm trying to upgrade version 2.65 of nopCommerce to version 2.7.  We also have version 2.65 deployed on a public server, and I don't have any LinqToFacebook.dll in our bin folder.  I can find no evidence of any LinqToFacebook NuGet package either, so I'm thinking that this .dll was once required by older versions of NopCommerce and is no longer available.  My solution is to comment out the line in the `package.config` file and move on.  Later versions of nopCommerce do not require this .dll.